# Normal toggle switches don't fit flush in metal electrical box cover

Tags: electrical

I am trying to replace this old two toggle switch that burnt out in this 4-inch box in my basement:

[image]
[image]

However, every new switch has these ears the stick up and block it from sitting flush against the front cover. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Notice a slanted scribe-line on the "Mickey Mouse" ears? They show where to bend the ear, using pliers, to break it off. Bend once or twice and the ears snap off. You can save them to use as washers, if you want. Or loan 'em to Marcus Antonius.

Comment: Just confirming that you've identified and fixed the issue that caused them to get "burnt" in the first place. That's not a normal thing and isn't to be expected. It's an indication that _something_ is wrong somewhere...

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that follow up concern. The house was built in 1973 and we bought it in November 2019. This switch has never worked and was inoperable from day one, so it may have been that way for a while. Other than seeing if it happens again what could I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Those ears snap off

Those are called "plaster ears" and can be broken off using a pair of pliers.  Snapping them off will let you fit the new switch into the existing box.

Comment: End of central tab also snaps off.